# Aligning multiple elements in <th>

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code for a table which works okay:

```
<table class="table table-striped as-table">
    <thead class="as-table-head">
        <tr>
            <th>
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkBoxHead" style="margin-left: 7px;">
            </th>
            <th> <span>Status</span>

                <div class="btn-group pull-right">
                    <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                    <img class="as-table-head-dropdown-arrow" src="~/Content/img/hd-pop.png">
                    </a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="/app/1">Item A</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="/app/2">Item B</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="/app/3">Item C</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Key</th>
            <th>Download</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkBoxHead">
            </td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>stubby1</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>babdad1f-46a0-4149-abf6-f8e3649a9ade</td>
            <td>Download</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkBoxHead">
            </td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>stubby2</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>b8gkwd1f-9g74-4149-abf6-hgytkg49a97dmn</td>
            <td>Download</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.as-table-head {
    background-color:rgb(30, 36, 42);
    width:100%;
}
.as-table-head > tr > th {
    color:white;
    font: bold 13px/15px;
    padding:0 !important;
    height: 30px;
}
.as-table-head > tr > th:hover {
    background-color:#333e48;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/4289/embedded/result/)

The problem I am having is aligning the heading text ("Status") and the img. I would like the text **to be on the left** centered and the img **to be on the right** centered.

However, `margin-top` or `margin-bottom` doesn't seem to have an effect on either of these elements.

Also, it is required that the img and text be separate elements because they each need to have their own function when clicked.

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: u want to keep the text on middle and image on middle , wait i am confused!

Comment: @MohitBhasi, as i understand vertical align - middle :)

Comment: @MohitBhasi I've updated my question to try and clarify, I want one element to be on the left, and the other to be on the right.

Comment: They are on the left and on the right right now. you need to clarify further.

Comment: So do you want to align them vertically or horizontally?

Comment: @dfsq Align them vertically

Comment: What's the size of the image?

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları 8x5

Comment: @Tomcelic, it wasn't suggestion

Comment: @demo whoops, my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will be able to align cell content vertically for example like this:

```
<th class="valigned"> 
    <span>Status</span>
    <div class="btn-group pull-right"> 
        <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
            <img class="as-table-head-dropdown-arrow" src="~/Content/img/hd-pop.png" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <!-- ... -->
</th>
```

CSS:

```
.as-table-head .valigned:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Why it works: vertical-align is applied to inline/inline-block elements so they are aligned relatively to each other. In your case you have only one inline element (`span`), the `div` is floated so it's `block` level element. So what you can do is simply inject pseudo-element and make it `inline` so that `span` could be vertically aligned.

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/4300/

Comment: This is really nice solution but it doesn't work on FF for me.

Comment: Try to increase the height of `th` element to say `39px`.

Comment: It works with fixed height, but another problem appear - what if the height of the `th` element is dynamic -> if the table change width.